# Using aggregate to compute monthly weighted average

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I need to compute a monthly weighted average. The data frame looks like this:

```
            Month Variable Weighting
460773 1998-06-01       11    153.00
337134 1998-06-01        9      0.96
473777 1998-06-01       10    264.00
358226 1998-06-01        6      0.52
414626 1998-06-01       10     34.00
341020 1998-05-01        9      1.64
453066 1998-05-01        5     26.00
183276 1998-05-01        8      0.51
403729 1998-05-01        6    123.00
203005 1998-05-01       11      0.89
```

When I use `aggregate` e.g.,

```
 Output <- aggregate(Variable ~ Month, df , mean )
 Output
       Month Variable
1 1998-05-01      7.8
2 1998-06-01      9.2
```

I get correct results, however, when I try to add weight to the aggregation e.g.,

```
Output <- aggregate(Variable ~ Month, df , FUN = weighted.mean, w = df$Weighting)
```

I get a different-vector-lenghts error:

```
Error in weighted.mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

Is there a way to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `aggregate()` it is not possible, because your weight vector is not partitionated during `aggregate()`. You can use `by()` or `split()` plus `sapply()` or additional package `data.table` or function `ddply()` from package `plyr` or functions from the package `dplyr`

example with `split()` plus `sapply()`:

```
sapply(split(df, df$Month), function(d) weighted.mean(d$Variable, w = d$Weighting))
```

result:

```
1998-05-01 1998-06-01 
   5.89733   10.33142
```

a variant with `by()`

```
by(df, df$Month, FUN=function(d) weighted.mean(d$Variable, w = d$Weighting)) # or
unclass(by(df, df$Month, FUN=function(d) weighted.mean(d$Variable, w = d$Weighting)))
```

with package `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, ~Month, summarize, weighted.mean(Variable, w=Weighting))
```

with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, weighted.mean(Variable, w = Weighting), Month]
```

Comment: Thanks! that's helpful. Is there a way to disregard NAs? Since when these functions encounter NAs they automatically make the aggregate score as NA.

Comment: yes, `weighted.mean()` has a parameter `na.rm=`, read the documentation of the function.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had a syntax error that's why it didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, super useful. How will change the code if I would compute the weighted mean for more than one variable?

Comment: @LucaCoding `.(weighted.mean(Variable1, w = Weighting), weighted.mean(Variable2, w = Weighting))` if more ... then `lapply(...)`

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't have `plyr`, `dplyr` or `data.table` installed and cannot install them due to some reasons, it is still possible to use `aggregate` to compute monthly weighted average, all you need is to do the following trick,

```
df$row <- 1:nrow(df) #the trick
aggregate(row~Month, df, function(i) mean(df$Variable[i])) #mean
aggregate(row~Month, df, function(i) weighted.mean(df$Variable[i], df$Weighting[i])) #weighted mean
```

---

Here are the outputs:

Mean:

```
> aggregate(row~Month, df, function(i) mean(df$Variable[i]))
       Month row
1 1998-05-01 7.8
2 1998-06-01 9.2
```

Weighted mean:

```
> aggregate(row~Month, df, function(i) weighted.mean(df$Variable[i], df$Weighting[i]))
       Month      row
1 1998-05-01  5.89733
2 1998-06-01 10.33142
```